# Rails select() and count() don't seem to play nice

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've noticed something odd with Rails (4.1) ActiveRecord, where `select` and `count` sometimes mix badly:

```
User.all.count
 => 103
User.all.size
 => 103
User.all.length
 => 103
```

So far, so good. I can select on `id`:

```
User.select(:id).all.count
 => 103
User.select(:id).all.size
 => 103
User.select(:id).all.length
 => 103
```

Still good. I can also select on `email`:

```
User.select(:email).all.count
 => 103
User.select(:email).all.size
 => 103
User.select(:email).all.length
 => 103
```

But now problems begin. When I select on *both* `id` and `email`:

```
User.select(:id, :email).all.count
 (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(id, email) FROM `users`
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' email) FROM `users`' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(id, email) FROM `users`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' email) FROM `users`' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(id, email) FROM `users`

User.select(:id, :email).all.size
 (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(id, email) FROM `users`
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' email) FROM `users`' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(id, email) FROM `users`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' email) FROM `users`' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(id, email) FROM `users`

User.select(:id, :email).all.length
 => 103
```

Why is it that `count` and `size` (which in this case aliases to `count`) are throwing an exception, and only when I select *more than one* attribute?

Is there an explanation for this? I find this quite unexpected.

Comment: Have you tried without `.all` - `User.select(:id, :email).size` ?

Comment: @RichPeck I'm afraid that `User.select(:id, :email).size` throws the same exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in Rails 4.1.  See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13648

Comment: If you're affected by this bug, this issue talks about needing to pass :all to count. I.e. `User.select(:id, :email).count(:all)`

Comment: @camomileCase great tip.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `select` and you have more than one columns for an argument, you need to put it in a string, in this format:

```
User.select("id, email")
```

In other words, the list of columns should only be passed in [pure string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions) format

Comment: while the SQL that's generated is subtly different -- using symbols generates `SELECT 'users'.'id', 'users'.'email' FROM 'users'` and using the string generates `SELECT id, email FROM 'users'` -- I still get an exception when I run `User.select("id, email").size`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @camomileCase for your tip.

In my case I've resolved it by adding `count` with `:all` option, and sometimes adding an additional `count` if needed. This way works perfect for me:

```
@grid = myscope.select(:thickness, :width, :length, "SUM(quantity_available) as quantity_available").group(:thickness, :width, :length)

@grid.assets.limit(nil).count(:all)
@grid.assets.limit(nil).count(:all).count
```